# changing NSButton title color but not text

Tags: swift, macos

I was trying to change the title color of NSButton and I found this code and it worked, but I want to change only the color not the string

```
button.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "foo", attributes: [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.blackColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style ])
```

When I remove the `string : "foo"` Xcode gives me this error:

```
"Argument labels '(attributes:)' do not match any available overloads"
```

How can I only change the color of the button without changing the title text as I am looping through the view controller to change all the NSButtons title colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the current title string of the button:

```
button.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(
    string: button.title,
    attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.blackColor(), 
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To update attributedTitle first you need to get button text then update color.

Something like,

```
if let attributedTitle = button.attributedTitle.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString {
    attributedTitle.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.black, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedTitle.length))
    button.attributedTitle = attributedTitle
}
```